# Google Maps API: Getting coordinates of current location iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, location, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am currently working with Google Maps API in my project. I am trying to set the default camera/zoom to the users location. I do this:

```
@implementation ViewController{

GMSMapView *mapView_;

}
@synthesize currentLatitude,currentLongitude;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
mapView_.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;


}
- (void)loadView{

CLLocation *myLocation = mapView_.myLocation;

GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(myLocation.coordinate.latitude, myLocation.coordinate.longitude);
marker.title = @"Current Location";
marker.map = mapView_;
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:myLocation.coordinate.latitude
                                                        longitude:myLocation.coordinate.longitude
                                                             zoom:6];
mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];

self.view = mapView_;
   NSLog(@"%f, %f", myLocation.coordinate.latitude, myLocation.coordinate.longitude);

}
```

However, it does not work, since when I do

```
NSLog(@"%f, %f", myLocation.coordinate.latitude, myLocation.coordinate.longitude);
```

it returns 0, 0, and it does not give the current location coordinates. How can I properly get the user's coordinates?

Comment: What is this line doing ?
CLLocation *myLocation = mapView_.myLocation;

To get current location, we need to 
1. Add CoreLocation Framework
2. Create an object of CLLocationManager
CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
3. [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];

Comment: Google Maps has a function that gets the user's location, but i do not know how to get it

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16331767/how-to-get-current-location-in-google-map-sdk-in-iphone
Hope It helps

Comment: I looked at that one, but it doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: when i use it i got blank screen, i am showing the map on a custom view and want to get latitude , longitude of current location ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

.h

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
@property(nonatomic,retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
```

.m

```
- (NSString *)deviceLocation 
{
NSString *theLocation = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"latitude: %f longitude: %f", locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude, locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];
return theLocation;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; 
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100 m
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13491411/iphone-app-how-to-get-the-current-location-only-once-and-store-that-to-be-used).

Comment: You'll need to call `[super viewDidLoad];` in your own implementation of `viewDidLoad`

Comment: After initializing, you need to set the delegate; otherwise, won't work. In Swift: `locationManager.delegate = self`You need to conform to the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` delegate and implement `func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {...}`. You may also want to stop updating the location at some point: `self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()`

Answer (score 6):

When an app first starts it may not yet know your location, as it usually takes a while for the GPS device to lock on to your location (if it has just been started), and especially if this is the first time the application has been run, and so the user hasn't yet answered the prompt to give the app access to their location. Also it seems like `mapView.myLocation` is always empty (either nil or has coordinates 0,0) when the map view has just been created.

So you will need to wait until the user's location is known, and then update the camera position.

One way might be using the code at [how to get current location in google map sdk in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16331767/how-to-get-current-location-in-google-map-sdk-in-iphone) as suggested by Puneet, but note that the sample code there is missing the details of setting up the location manager (like setting the location manager's delegate), which might be why it didn't work for you.

Another option could be to use KVO on `mapView.myLocation`, as described here: [about positioning myself,some problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15266118/about-positioning-myself-some-problems)

By the way in your sample code you are accessing `mapView.myLocation` before you create the `mapView`, and so the location would always be nil anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I just Downloaded the new GoogleMap SDK Demo for iOS. Here is what I have seen from the source code that how the "Current Location" is achieved via KVO.

```
#if !defined(__has_feature) || !__has_feature(objc_arc)
#error "This file requires ARC support."
#endif

#import "SDKDemos/Samples/MyLocationViewController.h"

#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>

@implementation MyLocationViewController {
  GMSMapView *mapView_;
  BOOL firstLocationUpdate_;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.868
                                                          longitude:151.2086
                                                               zoom:12];

  mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
  mapView_.settings.compassButton = YES;
  mapView_.settings.myLocationButton = YES;

  // Listen to the myLocation property of GMSMapView.
  [mapView_ addObserver:self
             forKeyPath:@"myLocation"
                options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                context:NULL];

  self.view = mapView_;

  // Ask for My Location data after the map has already been added to the UI.
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
  });
}

- (void)dealloc {
  [mapView_ removeObserver:self
                forKeyPath:@"myLocation"
                   context:NULL];
}

#pragma mark - KVO updates

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context {
  if (!firstLocationUpdate_) {
    // If the first location update has not yet been recieved, then jump to that
    // location.
    firstLocationUpdate_ = YES;
    CLLocation *location = [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];
    mapView_.camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithTarget:location.coordinate
                                                     zoom:14];
  }
}

@end
```

Hope it can help you.

Comment: This method is quite a long one and it would be better if we go for CLLocation Manager.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone wants DrDev's excellent answer in Swift 3:

```
var locationManager: CLLocationManager?

func deviceLocation() -> String {
    let theLocation: String = "latitude: \(locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude) longitude: \(locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude)"
    return theLocation
}

func viewDidLoad() {
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
    // 100 m
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```