# Google Maps API, Show Current User Location

Tags: objective-c, google-maps

I'm currently using the following code to position the camera on my Google Map:

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:49.282237
                                                            longitude:-123.125966

                                                                 zoom:13];
        mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
```

Instead of having the camera zoom in to those coordinates, how can I get it to zoom in to a user's current location? I can't seem to sort out that code; any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API: Getting coordinates of current location iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17057805/google-maps-api-getting-coordinates-of-current-location-ios)

Comment: @Marco That answer works, but doing it that way a)shows my current location, but doesn't zoom IN to my location and b) wipes out all of my existing markers (showing nearby locations).